# Modulo operator with nonintegers - unexpected results

Tags: datatypes, floating-point

**MySQL 5.5.32, Oracle 11g**

MySQL returns strange results for queries involving [`mod()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) with noninteger moduli. Why is this?

I have a column defined thus:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col    | double(15,6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have selected a known value from that column to use for testing - 5850. If I query the table, testing that column for whole numbers, I get these results:

```
mysql> SELECT thing_id,name FROM table WHERE col=5850 AND mod(col,1) != 0;
Empty set (1.07 sec)
```

This is expected. But this is not:

```
mysql> SELECT thing_id,name FROM table WHERE col=5850 AND mod(col,.1) != 0;
+-----------+-----------+
| thing_id  | name      |
+-----------+-----------+
|   4444444 | some      |
|   4444445 | names     |
...
|  55555555 | go        |
|  55555556 | here      |
+-----------+-----------+
416 rows in set (1.07 sec)
```

The same results from substituting `col MOD .1` and `col % .1` so it has to do with the computation not the semantics.

Compare this with the behavior of Oracle (using SQL Developer if that matters), where the type of `col` is `NUMBER`:

```
SELECT thing_id,name FROM table WHERE col=5850 AND mod(col,.1) != 0;
thing_id    name
[NO RECORDS]
```

The precision on the MySQL column seems to make this difference, but I don't understand how. Conceptually, shouldn't `integer_value % .1 = 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start with a link: **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**.

In short, float-point arithmetic types, like the `float` and `double` mysql types should never be used for precise arithmetic. And your `col mod 0.1` is trying to do exactly that, a precise arithmetic check. It is trying to find if the value in `col` is an exact multiple of `0.1`. And it fails miserably, as it is obvious from your results.

**The solution is to use a fixed type, like `decimal(m, n)`** to do these types of checks.

As for why you got different results in Oracle, it's because you used `NUMBER` which is implemented differently (with decimal precision). The equivalents in Oracle of float and double are `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE` and use binary precision. See the notes in Oracle docs: [Overview of Numeric Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209):

> Oracle Database provides two numeric datatypes exclusively for floating-point numbers: `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE`. They support all of the basic functionality provided by the `NUMBER` datatype. However, while **`NUMBER` uses decimal precision**, `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE` use binary precision. This enables faster arithmetic calculations and usually reduces storage requirements.
>
> **Note:**
> `BINARY_DOUBLE` and `BINARY_FLOAT` implement most of the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, IEEE Standard 754-1985 (IEEE754).

---

If you insist to use `double` (I see no reason why), a few more tests with the `mod` operator/function in mysql, reveals that:

When you use integers for the arguments, say you do `x mod K`, the result is always an integer between `0` and `K-1`. The expected mathematical behaviour.

When you use floats/doubles, say you do `x mod K`, the result is any number from `0.0` to `K` **included**. (as your tests which show `5850.0 mod 0.1` to result in `0.1`). I haven't done millions of tests, so there may be cases where the result can even be larger than `K`! Floating-point arithmetic can give weird results.

So, a workaround (which may not always work!) would be to use this condition:

```
( mod(col, 0.1) <> 0.0  AND  mod(col, 0.1) <> 0.1 )
```

---

To be honest, I feel sad I even made the workaround suggestion. Please read again the **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)** and don't use the workaround.

**Use fixed-precision types for precision arithmetic operations.**